# Prolog: Unhandled exception: pce(object) `@prolog_warnings/emacs_hit_list' does not exist

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, xpce

I wrote some days ago about a problem with **imported_procedures** and I was thinking turning off autoloading of libraries.
So I used the command `:- set_prolog_flag(autoload, false).` and now I receive this error:

```
Unhandled exception: pce(object) `@prolog_warnings/emacs_hit_list' does not exist
```

I don't even know what this error is: I tried to search online *emacs_hit_list* for an answer but I didn't find anything.
What should I do?

In case you're wondering what I'm using: I'm using SWI-Prolog 8.2.1. The code that generates the error is this:

```
vertices(G, Vs) :-
   findall(V, vertex(G, V), Vs).
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PCE is the interface of object-oriented systems of SWI-Prolog, see [An Architecture for Making Object-Oriented Systems Available from Prolog](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0207053), 2002. `@prolog_warnings` seems to be the reference to the window to display errors and warnings. I'm not completely sure what's going but this error message comes from the interface to the windowing system, not your code. You are probably using the built-in editor started by predicate `emacs/0`?

Comment: Yup, I'm using emacs for writing in Prolog. 
So there's no way to fix it?

Comment: I don't know. This is question about interna. Maybe try in on the SWI-Prolog mailing list: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/

Comment: This is cross posted at [SWI-Prolog Forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/prolog-error-unhandled-exception-pce-object-prolog-warnings-emacs-hit-list-does-not-exist/2934t)